Lie algebras over finite field
The 3-dimensional Lie algebras over a finite field $\mathbf{F}_q$ are still the same as the 3-dimensional Lie algebras over $\mathbf{C}$?
Shamsaki, Erfanian, and Parvizi [1] extend the definition of the degree of commutativity to Lie algebras over finite fields that exist for groups.

Definition Let $\mathfrak g$ be a finite-dimensional Lie algebra over the field $\mathbf{F}_q$. The commutativity degree of $\mathfrak g$ is defined as
the ratio
$$ d(\mathfrak g)=\frac{|\{(x, y) \in \mathfrak g \times \mathfrak g \mid[x, y]=0\}|}{|\mathfrak g|^2} . $$

The authors Shamsaki, Erfanian, and Parvizi  [2] make the following remark:

In [3], Lescot proved that all groups with $d(G)>\frac{1}{2}$ are
nilpotent. In the subsequent theorem, we prove that there exists a
non-nilpotent Lie algebra $\mathfrak g$ with $d(\mathfrak g)>\frac{1}{q}$, which proves
that the above fact does not hold for Lie algebras.

This commentary motivated me to look at the case of 3-dimensional Lie algebras but with non-nilpotency in mind.
The ranking list can be used to demonstrate the following:
Any non-abelian and non-nilpotent  3-dimensional Lie algebra $ \mathfrak g$ has degree of commutativity lower than that of the Heisenberg algebra $\mathfrak h_3$.
But looking at the literature, it is not clear to me if the Lie algebras of this classification are the same for finite fields (I am an amateur, sorry).
The classification: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_low-dimensional_real_Lie_algebras
[1] Shamsaki, Afsaneh, Ahmad Erfanian, and Mohsen Parvizi. "On the commutativity degree of a finite-dimensional Lie algebra." arXiv preprint arXiv:2406.10064 (2024).
[2] Shamsaki, Afsaneh, Ahmad Erfanian, and Mohsen Parvizi. "On the values of commutativity degree of Lie algebras." arXiv preprint arXiv:2406.10077 (2024).
[3] Lescot, Paul. Sur certains groupes finis.” Rev. Math. Sp´ eciales 8 (1987): 276-277.

The classification is different. First of all, there are infinitely many complex solvable Lie algebras of dimension $3$, but of course only finitely many over a finite field. Secondly, the classification is really different in prime characteristic, even for simple Lie algebras, in particular for characteristic $p=2$. Then we have a simple Witt algebra $W(1,\underline{2})^{(1)}$, and $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\Bbb F)$ is no longer simple in characteristic $2$.
A complete classification for dimension $3$ is available in the literature. For the solvable case in dimension $3$ over arbitrary fields, see for example the work of Willem de Graaf here. Every non-solvable Lie algebra is perfect in dimension $3$. The classification then is easier than in the solvable case.

Thank you!!!
Isn't there a classification of 3-dimensional Lie algebras except isomorphism on finite fields?
